# Why dosen't setting the className style the React element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have been trying to add style element to my React, when I would do the following, the style does not show up:

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.3/babel.js"></script>
    <style>
      .box {
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .box--large {
        width: 270px;
        height: 270px;
      }

      .box--medium {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
      }

      .box--small {
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
      const element = (
        <div>
        <div className="box box--small">small lightblue box</div>
      </div>
        );
      ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement);
    </script>
</body>
```

But, when I change the code to the following, it works:

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.3/babel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
      const element = (
       <div>
        <div className="box box--small" style={{fontStyle: 'italic',backgroundColor: 'lightblue',width: "90px",height: "90px"}}>small lightblue box</div>
      </div>
        );
      ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement);
    </script>
</body>
```

Essentially, moving the style to the div element when I declare it adds the styling. I understand why the second one works, but why dosen't the first one work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your css is not applied to the element is not becuase your class is not applied to the element but because your css is removed from the page.
You see you added all your scripts and also your styles into the `<div>` that is used to render your react app. React replaces the contents of that div which removes your styles in your first example.

The second example worked because react rendered the style itself and didn't rely on the stylesheet.

*(Just FYI and I'm sure you know this through various tutorials but react is not usually rendered and transpiled in the browser)*

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your react app</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.3/babel.js"></script>
    <style>
        .box {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .box--large {
            width: 270px;
            height: 270px;
        }

        .box--medium {
            width: 180px;
            height: 180px;
        }

        .box--small {
            width: 90px;
            height: 90px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
        const element = (
            <div>
            <div className="box box--small">small lightblue box</div>
        </div>
            );
        ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a string (more on that later):
There are few way you can write style in React.

```
1. inline styling
class MyHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={{color: "red"}}>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

2. javascript object

class MyHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const mystyle = {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue",
      padding: "10px",
      fontFamily: "Arial"
    };
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={mystyle}>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

3. External stylesheet
App.css:
- Create a new file called "App.css" and insert some CSS code in it:

body {
  background-color: #282c34;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

- Import the stylesheet in your application:

index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';

class MyHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Hello Style!</h1>
      <p>Add a little style!.</p>
      </div>
    );

}
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyHeader />, document.getElementById('root'));

4. css modules 
mystyle.module.css:
- Create a new file called "mystyle.module.css" and insert some CSS code in it:

.bigblue {
  color: DodgerBlue;
  padding: 40px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

- Import the stylesheet in your component:

App.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styles from './mystyle.module.css'; 

class Car extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1 className={styles.bigblue}>Hello Car!</h1>;
  }
}

export default Car;
```